# Adobe Acrobat Reader version 10/11 & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, adobe-reader

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I have enabled the partners repo & installed Adobe Reader 9.5.5 OK. Unfortunately, I need Adobe Reader version 10 or 11 for the particular .pdf file I'm using. If anyone is interested, the .pdf file is a file supplied by UK's HMRC for Company Returns which requires certain Trust settings to be made. Can anybody tell me where I can download an appropriate (to Ubuntu 14.04) Adobe Reader 10/11 install file?
PS I've tried Adobe's web site & internet searched.

Comment: Adobe decided that all us Linux users don't amount to anything in the world, and stopped releasing Adobe Reader for linux a while back.

Comment: Ask that company to provide you a Windows Licence or something. Tell them that if they provide an encoded (to PDF) file with none or obscure way (in this case) to read it - that means they do not provide you the file at all.

Comment: What about using Evince instead? Anything is better than Acrobat Reader anyway!

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try to install the [Adobe Reader with Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3156).

---

the last native version was [adobe reader 9](https://www.adobe.com/products/reader/tech-specs.html#9), newer versions are only available for Windows and MacOS.

Comment: i would recommend http://pdfreaders.org/ for an overview of the alternatives.

Comment: I tried installing Adobe Reader with latest version of Wine (from Ubuntu Wine Team). It installed OK but didn't work: some dll problem but I forget what it was.

Comment: No point in trying alternatives as it needs special Adobe Reader trust settings.

Comment: as described in the link: you will need wine 1.7 and winetricks.

Comment: it was just a comment to point out some alternatives for other users reading this...

Answer (score 0):

Only solution was to install Adobe Reader for Windows XP: I have Windows XP running as a VM using VirtualBox. That worked OK. Hopefully, this problem will not be there for next year's company accounts & tax return as HMRC told me that they will not be using Adobe Reader writing to a downloaded (from HMRC) CT600 pdf file but will instead be completing a CT600 form directly on their website. This is the method used for HMRC personal tax returns, which work OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open it using Adobe on Android Tablet / or mobile. I am doing this in case I would like to use some features like adding comments or highlighting. I hope this works for you.